# Why is `apt-get update` telling me to run `apt-get update`?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I recently autoremoved my old unused kernels. At the end of the process it output this message:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get update` but got the same message at the end of that. So I ran it again and still got the same message.

What should I do now?

---

### Details

**sources.list.d**

- chris-lea-node_js-trustyy.list
- daniel_pavel-solaar-trusty.list
- daniel_pavel-solaar-trusty.list
- google.list
- google.chrome.list
- google-chrome.list.save
- google-talkplugin.list

**source.list** *(comments removed for brevity)*

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question AND the duplicate entry.

Comment: I see two `daniel_pavel-solaar-trusty.list` in that list. (Also next time, instead of making a list, just post the output of `ls -1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d`)

Answer (score 0):

You have duplication in your sources lists.  This usually occurs if you accidentally add the same repository twice.  check out `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and check for duplicates.

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in either. I'll add both to the question though incase I'm missing something, which is likely.